# PostgreSQL query: I want to find the count of each base in a DNA sequence

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 5 random DNA sequence (20 length DNA base), I want to find the base count.

In the first section, I have prepared a DNA length function to generate a sequence of 5 x 20 DNA base lengths. But I would like to find the base count. How many "A" is in the sequence, how many "C" is in the sequence, how many "G" is in the sequence, and how many "T" is in the sequence.

```
prepare dna_length(int) as
with t1 as (select chr(65) as s union select chr(67) union select chr(71) union select chr(84) )
, t2 as ( select s, row_number() over() as rn from t1)
, t3 as ( select generate_series(1,$1) as i,round(random() * 4 + 0.5) as rn )
, t4 as ( select t2.s from t2 join t3 on (t2.rn=t3.rn))
select array_to_string(array(select s from t4),'') as dna;

with t1 as (
    select 1 as rn, 'A' as s
    union select 2, 'C' 
    union select 3, 'T' 
    union select 4, 'G' 
), t2 as (
    select generate_series(1, 5) as sample
), t3 as ( 
    select t2.sample, generate_series(1,20) as i,
           round(random() * 4 + 0.5) as rn 
      from t2
), t4 as (
    select t3.sample, t3.i, t3.rn, t1.s
      from t3 
      join t1 on t1.rn = t3.rn
) 
select sample, string_agg(s, '' order by i) 
  from t4
 group by sample
 order by sample;
```

Right now it looks like this:

```
id          DNA          
1   ACTGCTGCAGTCGTACGTAC 
2   TGCAGTCGTAGCTGACGTAG 
3   GCAGTGACCAACGTGTGACA 
4   TGACGTGTCGAGACGAAGAG 
5   CGTGTGAGAGTCGTAGAGTG
```

The result should look like this:

```
id          DNA            A   C   G   T
1   ACTGCTGCAGTCGTACGTAC   4   6   5   5
2   TGCAGTCGTAGCTGACGTAG   4   4   6   6
3   GCAGTGACCAACGTGTGACA   6   5   6   4
4   TGACGTGTCGAGACGAAGAG   4   3   8   3
5   CGTGTGAGAGTCGTAGAGTG   4   2   9   5
```

Comment: FYI - your counts are off.  For instance, for id = 1, there are 6 "C"s, 5 "G"s, and 5 "T"s

Comment: If you turn your final query into another CTE, you can query that and expose columns A, C, G, and T like this:
`length(DNA) - length(replace(DNA,'A',''))`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional counts in the final query:

```
with ...
select 
    sample, 
    string_agg(s, '' order by i) dna,
    count(*) filter(where s = 'A') a,
    count(*) filter(where s = 'C') c,
    count(*) filter(where s = 'G') g,
    count(*) filter(where s = 'T') t
from t4
group by sample
order by sample;
```